# How to Set User Defined value in a label

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on an JavaFX application and I have to set system related information in a JavaFX label.

I am doing like given as below:

```
systemInfo.setHdUsageTxt(Integer.toString(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()));
```

Here `hdUsageTxt` is a JavaFX label in which I have to set number of available processors at a time. But it is not setting String or Integer value in this label. And giving exception. Please suggest which type of data JavaFX label and TextField takes and how to set value in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
systemInfo.getHdUsageTxt().setText(Integer.toString(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()));
```

if didn't help, post your exception stack trace.
Both `javafx.scene.control.Label` and `javafx.scene.control.TextField` have a text property which is type of `javafx.beans.property.StringProperty`. You can access to this property's value with `setText(String text)` and `getText()`.